# Debian 8 - Jessie - Broken Packages / Dependency Hell

Tags: debian, dependencies

I'm having issues installing packages and doing upgrades.

If I execute `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gksu:i386 : Depends: sudo:i386
             Recommends: gnome-keyring:i386 but it is not installed
 guitarpro6:i386 : Depends: libportaudio0:i386 but it is not installed
                   Depends: libssl0.9.8:i386 but it is not installed
 libcairo2:i386 : Depends: libpixman-1-0:i386 (>= 0.30.0) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libxcb-render0:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libxcb-shm0:i386 but it is not installed
 libgconf-2-4:i386 : Depends: libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 (>= 0.78) but it is not installed
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 : Depends: libjasper1:i386 but it is not installed
                           Depends: libtiff5:i386 (>= 4.0.3) but it is not installed
 libgksu2-0:i386 : Depends: libgtop2-7:i386 (>= 2.22.3) but it is not installed
                   Depends: xauth:i386 but it is not installed
                   Recommends: sudo:i386
 libgtk2.0-0:i386 : Depends: libcups2:i386 (>= 1.6.0) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libxcomposite1:i386 (>= 1:0.3-1) but it is not installed
 libpango-1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libthai0:i386 (>= 0.1.12) but it is not installed
 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libharfbuzz0b:i386 (>= 0.9.9) but it is not installed
 libstartup-notification0:i386 : Depends: libxcb-util0:i386 (>= 0.3.8) but it is not installed
 wine-development : Depends: wine64-development (>= 1.7.29-4) but it is not installed or
                             wine32-development (>= 1.7.29-4)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

If i do a `sudo apt-get upgrade -f`, it tries to uninstall critical applications:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gksu:i386 libgksu2-0:i386 sudo task-desktop task-gnome-desktop xinit xorg
```

`dpkg --print-architecture`
`amd64`

`dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`
`i386`

Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like a multiarch issue. Please [edit] your question and add the output of i) `dpkg --print-architecture` and ii) `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`. Also, tell us what Debian you're using.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as you with interoperability of amd64 and i386 libraries when trying to run Skype on 64-bit Debian.

Comment: Does skype work if you use the webclient through your browser?

Comment: I think i'm fixed!

Comment: I did the following:
sudo aptitude remove gcc-4.9-base:i386
(i had to select "n" to the first 2 solutions and "y" to the 3rd solution which involved installing a stack of i386 packages)
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get clean
sudo updatedb
sudo apt-get install gksu